# React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> breaks defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-props, react-proptypes

I had this following code for the PropTypes of my button styled component

```
export type Props = {
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large',
};

StyledButton.defaultProps = {
  size: 'medium',
};
```

It was working fine but then I wanted to include HTMLButtonElement props to provide interactivity to my button. Therefore I added this:

```
export type Props = React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> & {
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large',
};

StyledButton.defaultProps = {
  size: 'medium',
};
```

However, this change makes defaultProps complains. This is the error, I am getting.

```
Types of property 'size' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
```

However, If I take away the React.HTMLProps, it works, but that's not what I want. Does anybody know a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to define a new interface:

```
export interface Props extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large',
};
```

The problem is that `React.HTMLProps` or rather, its superinterface `HTMLAttributes` already contains a `size` attribute defined as:

```
size?: number;
```

Therefore, you will have to rename your property.

Comment: I've got this error `Type '"small"' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.ts(2430).` ... it seems I can't override the prop size

Comment: @Neill Updated answer. You have a collision with an existing HTML attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I also found that simply extending `React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>` does not work if you want to set custom value for `size` prop. Here's a solution for this problem. We're going to need
small helper called `Omit` from `utility-types` package (https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#omitt-k)

And use it like this:

```
import { Omit } from 'utility-types';

type BaseButtonProps = Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>, 'size'>;

interface ButtonProps {
  size?: 'lg' | 'sm';
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps & BaseButtonProps> = ({ size }) => {
  // size is now 'lg', 'sm' or undefined
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So try these, as I looked at the site https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-typescript-and-defaultprops-dilemma-ca7f81c661c7

```
type Props = Partial<DefaultProps>;

type DefaultProps = Readonly<typeof defaultProps>;

const defaultProps = {
  size: 'small' as 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
};

export YourClass extends React.Component<Props> { }
```

That is the simplest easiest way, perhaps, of solving your issue, although there are others there that might help if that doesn't.

Comment: I am using styled components

Answer (score 0):

The `HTMLProps` type already includes a `size`.

I recommend using `ButtonHTMLAttributes` instead:

```
type Props = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & {
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large',
};
```